# BroadCastReceiver not receving data?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a Broadcast that sends user's LatLng information. In another activity, I have a Broadcast receiver that is supposed to receive this LatLng information and display it on map as heatmap. Heatmaps are working fine but I think the Broadcast is either not being sent or not being received, can't figure out exactly what's the problem. Maybe I am setting these up incorrectly? What I am trying to achieve is to display all users of my app on the map as a heatmap point. Maybe this is an entirely wrong approach for that matter?

Sender:

```java
    private void broadcastUserData(String userId, Double longitude, Double latitude) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("VRUId", userId);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        intent.setAction("VRUData");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Receiver:

```
    final Map<String, LatLng> map = new HashMap<>();
    private void createBroadcastReceiverVRUData() {
        // just for testing
        map.put("!2321", new LatLng(7.447893883296565, 9.48882099800934));
        map.put("!2321", new LatLng(7.44789382565, 9.4888204));
        map.put("!2231", new LatLng(7.447780625, 9.489011));
        initializeHeatMap(map);

        broadcastReceiverVRUData = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String userId = intent.getStringExtra("VRUId");
                LatLng gps = new LatLng(
                        intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0),
                        intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0));

                if (map.containsKey(userId)) {
                    map.remove(userId);
                    map.put(userId, gps);
                } else {
                    map.put(userId, gps);
                }

                initializeHeatMap(map);
                Log.d("THIS IS GPS", gps.toString());
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("VRUData");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                broadcastReceiverVRUData, intentFilter);
    }
```

Heatmap:

```java
    List<LatLng> list;
    private void initializeHeatMap(Map<String, LatLng> map) {
        list = new ArrayList<LatLng>(map.values());
        Log.d("GPS coordinates", map.values().toString());

        HeatmapTileProvider mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().data(list).build();


        mMap.addTileOverlay((new TileOverlayOptions()).tileProvider(mProvider));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`intent.setAction("VRUData")` is not the same `intentFilter.addAction("VRUDATA")` - one is in all caps.

Comment: put below code in the onCreate of your Activity. Need to initialise the app 
  --> `IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("VRUDATA");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                broadcastReceiverVRUData, intentFilter);`    Refer this for more: http://android--kotlin.blogspot.com/2018/12/fatal-exception-android-app-remoteserviceexception-cant-deliver-broadcast.html

Comment: I'm afraid that this didn't help either. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try First Thing: you can try gmap.clear(); before adding marker on map, might be the issue with old marker can not replace with new marker.

Try Second Thing :

Your receiver look like this in your activity or whatever where you are using.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;


receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             // put your stuuf here
               Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
               HashMap<String, String> mData;
             }
      }:
```

Comment: I am afraid that none of your suggestions helped ! I define the BroadcastReceiver in a method which is called in onCreate, so I don't see how your implementation is different than mine